# FTP or SCP file transfers without .DS_Store files

Tags: macos, ssh, ftp, file-transfer, .ds-store

I'm searching for a way to not transfer `.DS_Store` files when launching FTP or SCP transfers for a directory.

Is it possible to block `.DS_Store` files from being transferred along with the other files I'm moving?

I'm actually using FileZilla app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under Filezilla client, you can configure it to block some file extensions.

In **View** >> **Filename filters**... you have to create a new filter. Go to **Edit filter rules...** and  **New**. Look the existing filter called "**Useless Explorer files**" to adapt to Mac OSx files like .DS_Store

From [FileZilla oficial forums](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=24143)

Regards

Comment: i checked your since dunno why maybe you read in my thoughts  i'm using fileZilla actually :P thank you man!

Comment: @sbaaaang Just a small tip: Next time, please mention what program you're using. This will get you better answers without others having to read your mind ;) Thanks

Comment: @slhck yeah i was going to edit the question indeed sorry

Comment: There is a peace :p

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) as a client, it will automatically skip those files (and several others) during transmission.

[image]

This applies to both FTP and SFTP connections.

---

If you're going command-line, you should use `rsync` instead of `scp`. With `rsync` you can add the option `--exclude='.DS_Store'` to skip  those.

Comment: No, the second one in the list is `.DS_Store`. The first one is `.*~\..*`, so it matches the tilde-backup files. Regular dotfiles will be transmitted.

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry, I missed the lack of a `|`.

Comment: +1 thank you, i'm using FileZilla but it's nice also for using Cyberduck eheh